# Auto fill database name on query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 express.
I have databases named by year and an "ID", for example:

```
2010CB
2010PL
2011CB
2011YK
2012CB
2013CB
...
20NNCB
```

And I have to do a query that detects the last year with "CB", so that:

```
SELECT * FROM [20NNCB][.DBO].FIELD; --being NN the higher year.
```

Any way? The years are upper than 2000 and lower than 2100.

Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure I am getting the question correct, but wouldn't something like the following work? 

`  SELECT TOP 1 name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
  WHERE name LIKE '%CB%'
  ORDER BY name Desc `

Comment: You might be better off using application code (.net, php, coldfusion, etc) to get the name of your database.  For example, in ColdFusion, it would be `year(now()) - 1 & 'CB'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the database name, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name
  FROM sys.databases
 WHERE name LIKE '%CB'
 ORDER BY name DESC
```

You could assign this to a variable, and then use that variable in building dynamic SQL if you wish.

```
DECLARE @dbName sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT TOP 1 @dbName = name
  FROM sys.databases
 WHERE name LIKE '%CB'
 ORDER BY name DESC

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '.[DBO].[TABLENAME];'
EXEC (@sql);
```